# Stay extension in the US and Visa stamp

Tags: visas, usa, passport-stamps, visa-extensions

I have had my staying in the US limited for 3 weeks only , with a stamp on my passport , when I was intending to spend 3 months as a maximum or just as long as i can stay in the country since Im visiting both my best friend and boyfriend.

What can I do to have my staying extended as much as possible ?

Comment: Did your limited admission just happen randomly, or did the border guards give you some kind of indication of _why_ you got only 3 weeks?

Comment: In what status were you admitted?

Comment: Also when you entered did you tell the CBP officer you intended to stay 3 months, or is the 3 weeks you got the stay you requested?

Comment: No they interrogated me and searched my bags and based on important papers I have , and also the way back ticket , they thought was coming to get married , so they admitted for 3 weeks after an hour of a very long investigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should check your [I-94](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/) to make sure that you were only admitted for 3 weeks. Sometimes they write the wrong date next to the entry stamp.

If you want to stay for longer than you were admitted for, you can apply for Extension of Status with [Form I-539](https://www.uscis.gov/i-539). It costs $370. You must make sure to file it such that it is officially received by USCIS before the date on your I-94. You can stay in the US while the Extension of Status application is pending (and these days, it can be pending for 3-5 months), even if it's after the date on your I-94.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the above is true only if you entered on a visa. If you entered on the Visa Waiver Program, you cannot apply for Extension of Status.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me that OP wasn't admitted under the VWP, in which case, as I know you know, she is generally ineligible to extend her status.

Comment: Does the application have to be 40 days before the date that the stamp defines ? (the departure date they the customs defined  ? ) 

Will the  application (if ever possible) impact my profile ?  since I am planning on applying  for an immigration Visa once I get back home, to come again and get married to my fiance who's American .

Comment: @StarfallShaimie: No, it just has to be filed (officially received by USCIS, which may be a day or two after they receive it in the mail) before the date on your I-94. It should not affect an immigrant visa.

Comment: @user102008 USCIS is abreviation for what please ? so the moment they recieve my application i will be able to stay till the application is proceeded ? and I will not be considered as over stay ?

Comment: @StarfallShaimie: US Citizenship and Immigration Services. They are the ones who adjudicate Extension of Status applications. As long as it was timely received, you can stay until a decision is made.